# How to convert data from a csv into a collection of monthly case counts for each year in python

Tags: python-3.x

If I am given this data in a csv file

```
year,month,sex,age
2005,APR,M,19
2006,MAR,F,45
2007,MAY,M,67
2008,MXX,F,22
```

how would I 'index' the year and month out and count the number of times each occurs and returns something like this:

```
  Jan to Dec 2005           Jan to Dec 2006         
([[0,0,3,4,10 .... 9, 0], [2,3,5,6.....10,8], ......], 3, 1)
```

so it would count the number of inputs there are for January 2005, February 2005, March 2005... up to December 2008. Each year will be its own list and the last two elements are the number of valid inputs (3) and the number of invalid inputs (1, (something like the month or year was typed incorrectly))

I've tried two different ways and I'm struggling to figured out how to index just the month and year this is what I've gotten so far

```
def parse(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    info = file.read()

    data = info.split('\n')
    num = data[1:]


    total = len(num)

    months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP','OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'] 
    years = [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009] 

    table = []
```

Version 2

```
    file = open(filename)
    for i in file.readlines():
    values = i.split('\n')
    kyear, kmonth, ka, kx = values
```

I have had a look on here but the questions I've found weren't really what I'm trying to do, but, if anyone has seen a question like this that's already been answered please let me know

Comment: Is it vital that you have that slightly clumsy data structure as the output? It would seem to be easier to do this with dicts as the output. If you really wanted that structure you could build it later out of the dicts. How exactly do you see the invalid values for a year being attributed to a year if the year has been entered incorrectly? That seems to be a near impossible rule to apply. Your question raises a lot of questions that are blocking people being able to give you a useful answer. I am not sure SO is the right forum for the back and forward discussion that will be needed here.

Comment: @jwpfox - you are right at pointing the output format and result is very ambugious in the question, and probably will not be answered here in full, but I think it is not the most terrible question overall as it has the original dataset posted. The question owner would just need learn to separate reading the data (answered many times) and it transforming it (very custom case), I think.

Comment: @jwpfox - yes unfortunately that has to be the exact output, which is why I'm struggling so much. I'm pretty new to programming and this is my first time using SO is there any other place you could recommend going to for help?

Comment: @A1234 - better change the output format. Wherever it is derived from it, it is hard to understand and use.  Based on a 4 line dataset you posted, how do you derive the output?

Comment: @Evgeny Pogrebnyak - Totally agree it is an acceptable question. I just think that a forum like Dream In Code or similar would be a better match for the back and forward discussion that is going to be needed to get from the question to a meaningful answer. You can already see that my question about how an invalid year is being ignored because it is too hard to handle amongst all the other basic questions that need to be handled. There is an answer supplied that is just a suggestion to use the csv module and a lot of clarifying questions. SO is a bad match for this process, better forums exist.

Comment: @jwpfox - ideally SO is MWE question site, that is very insightful on a top-voted end, but indeed gets flooded with ```howdoi+my complex scenario``` questions like this one. On a separate note I can see why people stay away from <http://www.dreamincode.net>, just by looking at its design. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a perfect CSV file, it is not a good idea to read the fiel as stream, much better use `csv` module, which has rich array of answeres at SO. May also llook at link [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/csv-parsing.html), very close to your dataset.

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

doc = """year,month,sex,age
2005,APR,M,19
2006,MAR,F,45
2007,MAY,M,67
2008,MXX,F,22"""

# recreating your file with data in python 3.6 
Path("mydata.csv").write_text(doc)

with open("mydata.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader]

# now you have your data inside interpreter as list of OrderedDicts
print(rows)
```

In more recent versions of python each elemet of rows is `OrderedDict`, I think earlier it was jsut dict.

From here you can go slicing/validating your raw data in a fashion simial to this:

```
valid_months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 
                'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP','OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'] 

# sample code to validate months
valid_rows = [row for row in rows if row['month'] in valid_months]
invalid_rows = [row for row in rows if row['month'] not in valid_months]

def get_count(rows, year, month):
    return sum([1 for row in rows if row['month']==month 
                and int(row['year']) == year])

# check get_count is working right
assert get_count(valid_rows, year=2005, month='APR') == 1

# hardcoded, but can determine these by lookup
start_year = 2005
end_year = 2008

#set grid example for valid months
reported_cases = {year:[get_count(valid_rows, year, month) for month in valid_months] 
                  for year in range(start_year, end_year+1)
                  for month in valid_months}
```

Comment: ([[0,0,3,4,10 .... 9, 0], [2,3,5,6.....10,8], ......], 3, 1)      - This is a count of cases (for example people with a cold) reported each month of the year. So for this part -  [0,0,3,4,10 .... 9, 0], there were 0 cases reported in January, 0 in feb, 3 in march (of 2005) etc. and it would continue on for each year.

Comment: So basically you want ```cold_cases = {2005:{1:0,2:0,3:4, 12:0}}``` and de able to pick ```cold_cases[year][month]```?

Comment: what is ```, 3, 1)``` then?

Comment: @ Evgeny Pogrebnyak - 3 is the number of valid entries for the year, 1 is the number of invalid entries for the year. The sum of those two is the sum of all 12 months. That's the description in the original question. I think you can see the problem BTW your conversion into a dict is **not** okay according to the OP's answer to my question about the data structure.

Comment: Sure, OP should his live a life in a wierd datastructure he proposed. Would you write your code like this? )

Comment: @jwpfox: ```It would seem to be easier to do this with dicts as the output.```. I'm confused about your stance on dicts. )

Comment: @Evgeny Pogrebnyak - Not my stance. From the OP "... because this is part of an assignment it has to be done a very particular way...". The OP needs to satisfy the needs of the homework assignment he is asking for help with. I think you are confused by more than my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    years = [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009] 
    months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP','OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'] 

    result_dict = {}    #I will use dictionary to count mounts in years

    for year in years:
        result_dict[year] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    input_list = read_csv("data.csv")
    invalid_input_count = 0

    for item in input_list[1:]:
        year = int(item[0])
        month = item[1]
        if (year not in years) or (month not in months):    #invalid
            invalid_input_count += 1
        else:
            result_dict[year][months.index(month)] += 1

    print(result_dict)  #To see what we have in dictionary

    result_list = []
    for key in sorted(result_dict.keys()):  #Walk on sorted years and append to result_list
        result_list.append(result_dict[key])

    valid_input_count = len(input_list) - 1 - invalid_input_count #All inputs - header - invalid inputs
    result_list.append(valid_input_count)
    result_list.append(invalid_input_count)

    print(result_list)

def read_csv(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        content = f.read()
    ret_list = []
    for row in content.split("\n"):
        ret_list.append(row.split(","))
    return ret_list

main()
```

Output for your csv example:

```
{2008: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2009: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2005: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2006: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2007: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 3, 1]
```

I hope that helps.

NOTE: You can use a module or another way to read csv file. I assumed the csv file has no empty line.

Comment: @A1234 Could you tell me whether my solution works or not?

Comment: thanks for the help, because this is part of an assignment it has to be done a very particular way, so it doesn't work but your answer is helping me get there

Comment: @A1234 Where is the problem? I think, second line in the output is what you want. If you tell me what is wrong, maybe I can help.